# Python feedparser can not read WordPress custom feeds

Tags: python, django, rss, feedparser

I'm Using `Python2.7` and `feedparser`. I need to read feed of a `wordpress` site. I could read some common feed tags like `title, content`, ... of each items from feed, but I couldn't read some `custom feed that added`.

The feed url is: http://www.aecinema.ir/feed/.

You can see image tag in each items that is an "Added feed" , but I could't read.

My code:

```
feed = feedparser.parse("http://www.aecinema.ir/feed/")

for item in feed["items"]:
    print item["title"],  item["image"]
```

also i read feed as bellow:

```
print feed.entries[0].title, feed.entries[0].image
```

But in each case the error is same.

error: `object has no attribute 'image'`

What is wrong  in code ??? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is good, but the feed is invalid. See [validation results](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aecinema.ir%2Ffeed%2F).

`<image>` isn't defined in [RSS 2.0 specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) as an `<item>` subelement, so feedparser doesn't handle them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, So According to RSS 2.0 specification, "enclosure" key Describes a media object that is attached to the item. So i must to asking Wordpress site Admin to defined "enclosure" key in feed instead of image ;).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in your feeds.entries[0] FeedParserDict the key for "image" does not exist. If you run

```
feed.entries[0].keys()
```

It will output the keys that are available. It does not include any key "image".

Comment: Yes, it doesn't include image key by this command. But did you see feed url: http://www.aecinema.ir/feed/? there are some image keys with medium and thumbnail size in each feed item! @Wasim